# Mockito says "Wanted but not invoked" but debugging test jumps into that method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have to deal with a legacy application that has no tests. So before I begin refactoring I want to make sure everything works as it is.

Now imagine the following situation:

```
public SomeObject doSomething(final OtherObject x, final String something) {
    if(x != null) {
        final String = someOtherMethod(x, something);
    }
}

protected String someOtherMethod(final OtherObject x, final String something) {
    ....
}
```

Now I want to make sure that protected method is called as well

So I did this

```
@InjectMocks // Yes there is more going on here
private MyTestObject myTestObject;

private MyTestObject spy;

private static final OtherObject VALID_OTHER_OBJECT = new OtherObject();

@Before
public void setup() {
    this.spy = Mockito.spy(myTestObject);
}

@Test
public void ifOtherObjectIsNotNullExpectSubMethodToBeCalled() {
    myTestObject.doSomething(VALID_OTHER_OBJECT, null);
    verify(spy).someOtherMethod(VALID_OTHER_OBJECT, null);
}
```

I get a failing test and "Wanted but not invoked..." for `someOtherMethod()`.
I jumped right into debug mode and checked. That method is called!

What could be the cause of this? Am I misusing the spy here?

**Edit:** I want to stretch that I know this is not what you typically test for, especially since `someOtherMethod(...)` has a non-void return-value here. But imagine the return value was `void`...

Basically I just want to understand why the spy fails here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [its Javadoc](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy(T)), `Mockito.spy(object)` creates a copy of the passed in object. Calling methods on the original passed in object then does not register on the spy, because the spy instance is not the same object.

Change `myTestObject.doSomething(...)` to `spy.doSomething(...)` and it should work.

Alternative (different way to achieve the same thing):
Consider using the `@Spy` annotation on your myTestObject.
Be sure to add `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` to your initialization method (in your junit test).
The `@Before` and `@Mock` annotations are useful as well.

Comment: Is it a deep copy?

Comment: @Sorona Not specified in the docs, but a quick check of source says no. Shallow copy only.

Answer (score 1):

I had one object creating another and that other object making calls. So I needed to make that internal object be using the spied reference instead. I used reflection and updated the reference using Whitebox.

```
TestAddressFragment fragment = spy(new TestAddressFragment());
AddressPresenter presenter = fragment.getPresenter();
Whitebox.setInternalState(presenter, "view", fragment );
```

Now my fragment could check if its method was called.

```
verify( fragment ).showAddress(any(), anyBoolean());
```